# When does this nonlinear system of equations have a solution?

Tags: nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

Consider the following system of equations
$$\begin{cases} ||x-k||_p = t\\ f(k+x) = f(k) \end{cases}$$
where $x \in R^n$, $k \in R^n$, $f: R^n \mapsto R$ is a convex function and $|| \cdot ||_p$ is the $L^p$ norm.
Given $k$, $t$ and $p$, my aim is to either prove that the system has no solutions or that it has at least one solution (the actual solutions are not relevant). Can I apply Newton's method? Does imposing additional constraints on $f$ make the problem tractable?

Comment: What do you mean by "nondecreasing" on $R^n$?

Comment: What do you mean prove that it has no solutions or that is has at least one solution? What else could happen?

Comment: @Hugo My bad, removed "nondecreasing"

Comment: @copper.hat Not being able to determine if it has a solution (and thus being forced to check every possible value)